# Вернуть индекс/данные списка (declare @list) при выборке (select) из списка

Tags: sql, sql-server

- Microsoft Sql Management studio

необходимо просмотреть права пользователя по страницам **(есть ли у Коли право видеть одну из страниц или все сразу (page1, page2, page3, page4, page5)) показать список разрешимых страниц**

я решила создать список id возможных страниц, которые я знаю и вписываю вручную и потом из таблицы 'пользовательские права' поискать id пользователя и id страницы, если есть данные показать (к примеру в таблице записывают Yes и No, и я ищу все строки с Yes относящиеся к Коле и странице x из списка)

`procedure sql`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetUserPageAcces
    -
@UserId int
AS
BEGIN

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ListPage table (IdPage int, PageName vacrchar(max))
    INSERT INTO @ListPage VALUES (1, 'page1'), (2, 'page2'), (3, 'page3'), (4, 'page4'), (5, 'page5')
    
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT SomePropertyAcces AS Access FROM MyTableWithUser
    WHERE UserId = @UserId AND PageId IN (select Id from @ListPage) AND SomePropertyAcces = 'YES'
    --return @ListPage
```

`на выходе`

```
    Access   
    YES
    YES
```

а как можно вернуть данные этого листа `ListPage`

`чтоб на выходе было =>`

```
    Access   PageName 
    YES      page2
    YES      page3
```

я попыталась join-ом, потом попыталась создать таблицу #into, но уменя не получается, и возможно вообще это не так делают ?

я могу показать Id (взятое из таблицы MyTableWithUser), но мне нужно именно название страницы => page1, а не 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используем JOIN:

```
SELECT SomePropertyAcces AS Access, PageName
FROM MyTableWithUser
JOIN @ListPage ON PageId = IdPage
WHERE UserId = @UserId AND SomePropertyAcces = 'YES'
```

Comment: `join @ListPage on @ListPage.IdPage= PageId` вот так не работает, а мне обычно ясней, когда я добавляю перед переменой откуда она взялась (La variable scalaire "@ListPage" doit être déclarée.)=>я подумала, я же еще прописала declare и почему не выходит, и тк я сама додумалась, чтоб искать в списке думаю может вообще не так ищут. Сейчас попробовала без названия те как Вы прописали `ON PageId = IdPage` и работает. И вот не понимаю, а в чем разница.

Comment: @Dev18 - `"@ListPage".IdPage = PageId` - вот так можно. Имя переменной нужно взять в двойные кавычки или квадратные скобки.

Comment: @Dev18 - `JOIN @ListPage LP ON LP.IdPage = PageId` - ещё вариант с алиасом.

Comment: Аааа, супер отлично. А почему это не распространяется на то, когда я обычную таблицу join делаю, там же все работает и без кавычек. И когда временную таблицу тоже работает без кавычек #into.... В любом случае, ок, исправила у себя. ✅✅✅

Comment: @Dev18 - я поискал, но нигде не могу найти объяснение такого поведения. Будем считать, что так работает парсер sql.